# A Question About the Elements of $\ell^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $\ell^2 = \{(z_n) : \sum |z_n|^2 < \infty\}$ where $(z_n) \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.

I just read a proof that made use of the fact that $(z_n) \in \ell^2 \implies (z_n)$ is Cauchy and hence $(z_n) \rightarrow z$ for some $z \in \mathbb{C}$ since $\mathbb{C}$ is complete.  But since in order for $\sum |z_n|^2 < \infty$ the $z_n \rightarrow 0$, don't we have that $z = 0$ necessarily?

That is, don't we have that each $(z_n) \in \ell^2$ satisfies that

$$
(z_n) = \left\langle z_1, z_2, \ldots \right\rangle
$$

whereby $z_n \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_{n}$ converges absolutely or conditionally, then $\lim_{n}x_{n}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Each element of $\ell^2$ is a sequence
$$(z_n) = \{ z_1,z_2, \ldots \}$$
and you are correct in that the terms in the sequence go to zero at the tail.

However, the statement about Cauchy-ness is about sequences of elements of $\ell^2$, that is, *sequences of sequences*.

\begin{align*}
(z_{n,1}) &= \{ z_{1,1}, z_{1,2}, z_{1,3} \ldots \}\\
(z_{n,2}) &= \{ z_{2,1},z_{2,2}, z_{2,3}, \ldots \}\\
&\vdots\\
&\downarrow\\
(z_n) &= \{z_1, z_2, z_3, \ldots \}
\end{align*}

Comment: I've never seen a requirement that elements of $\ell^2$ are represented as two-tailed sequences. I always see $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Why would this be a requirement?

Comment: @MPW My mistake, I had recently been working with $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. I will fix my answer.